# LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references. - path is correct

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texlive, latexmk, sublime-text

I am getting the following warnings when building my document:

```
However, there were warnings in your LaTeX source

    ./100DayIntro.tex:7: LaTeX Warning: Citation `Cook2009' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
    ./100DayIntro.tex:7: LaTeX Warning: Citation `Sandy2004' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
    ./100DayIntro.tex:7: LaTeX Warning: Citation `Devaul2001' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
    ./100DayIntro.tex:7: LaTeX Warning: Citation `Donnelly2010' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
    ./100DayIntro.tex: LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

I have my references added:

```
\bibliography{../../../../Articles/library}
```

and if I go via the terminal to where my tex file is and enter `../../../../Articles` I can see the `library.bib` file is there and I can open it and all the references are in there.

Why are these warnings showing and why are my references not being entered? I've seen elsewhere people saying to build the file a few times but that has not worked either.

EDIT:
Also when I type `\cite` on Sublime Text 2 I get the search bar opening to allow me to search references and it seems to be picking them all up fine.

I have a different tex file in an adjacent folder that builds with references fine, when I copied the paragraph from the non-compiling file into the compiling one it will no longer add the references I just get `[?]`

Comment: Have you recompiled the document several times?

Comment: Yea I'd came across that solution and tried it but no matter how many times I try it still does not work.

Comment: Depending on your `TeX` distribution and operating system it may be not allowed for `bibtex` to access files that are in the file tree *above* the folder where your .tex file is situated.

Comment: Hmmmm....interesting @BenediktBauer I'll try moving the file and see what happens. Btw I'm running Crunchbang (debian based)

Comment: @Colin747 If you are on linux and that was the cause for your issue then you could easily solve it by just symlinking your .bib file into the folder where your .tex is.

Comment: I moved the file to the same directory as the tex file and I am still getting the same problems.

Comment: See my edit in original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I ran `bibtex 100DayIntro.aux` it was showing an error in my aux file as I was using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`, I changed this to `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and it compiled fine first time.

Answer (score 5):

I used to have the same problem, but I solved using the capital letters in

`\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`

(I had previously

`\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}`

), Remember that linux is sensible to capital letters.

Comment: MiguelOlivares: Welcome to TeX.SE -- please use the formating utilities of this forum to markup your answer. Please have a look on http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting